# Collisions between SKPhysicsBodies being ignored

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm using sprite kit for physics and collision detection in my app.

I have some balls falling into a box. The inside of the box is defined using bodyWithPolygonFromPath

I drop some balls into the box and they fall straight through.

Here is the code for defining the box

```
SKSpriteNode* boxFront = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: [boxData objectForKey: @"box_image"]];
boxFront.position = CGPointMake(0, -screenHeight*0.22);
boxFront.zPosition = 10;
[self addChild: boxFront];

CGFloat offsetX = boxFront.frame.size.width * boxFront.anchorPoint.x;
CGFloat offsetY = boxFront.frame.size.height * boxFront.anchorPoint.y;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 3 - offsetX, 129 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 129 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 85 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 200 - offsetX, 85 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 200 - offsetX, 129 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 197 - offsetX, 129 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 196 - offsetX, 87 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 3 - offsetX, 87 - offsetY);

CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

boxFront.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
boxFront.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

SKShapeNode* shape = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
shape.path = path;
shape.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
shape.zPosition = 101;
shape.lineWidth = 2;
[boxFront addChild: shape];
```

The last bit with the SKShapeNode just draws out the outline of the box for debugging purposes. The box drawn is where I would expect the collision box to be.

Here is the code for the balls that I drop into the box.

```
SKSpriteNode* circle1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: @"ball.png"];
circle1.position = CGPointMake(0, screenHeight*0.7);
circle1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius: 20];
circle1.zPosition = 100;
[self addChild: circle1];

SKSpriteNode* circle2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: @"ball.png"];
circle2.position = CGPointMake(-10, screenHeight);
circle2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius: 20];
circle2.zPosition = 100;
[self addChild: circle2];
```

All instances of self in the above to snippets of code are the same SKNode which is attached directly to the SKScene.

Any suggestions on what might be causing the collision detection to be ignored?

Comment: And where are you adding boxFront to scene?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that line, it is definitely being added tho because I can see the image on the screen. I'll edit to add that in.

Comment: Try to add it after setting its physicsBody

Comment: I just tried that, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Try to use bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath instead of bodyWithPolygonFromPath

Comment: @Tiddly, just a note, your boxFront is at z position 10 and the balls are at z position 100.  You will want them all at the same z position to interact.

Comment: @Nicael Setting it to bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath seems to have fixed the problem. Not sure why the polygon one wouldn't work, it might have an issue with concave shapes maybe. It working now tho so thanks, if you make that comment an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Douglas I don't think that's true, now that it's working I tested it with variable z positions and they continued to interact.

Answer (score 0):

I don not see you declaring the `physicsBody.categoryBitMask` and `physicsBody.collisionBitMask` properties for either your box or balls. If you do not define those for your objects, your code will not know which physics bodies should interact with each other.

Comment: The default value should be to collide with everything according to the Apple docs. I tried setting them anyway just incase and it made no difference.